# Physical memory mapping and location of page tables

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, x86-64, paging, page-tables

I have a picture of the virtual address space of a process (for x86-64):

[image]

However, I am confused about a few things.

1. What is the "Physical memory map" region for?
2. I know the 4-page tables are found in the high canonical region but where exactly are they? (data, code, stack, heap or physical memory map?)

Comment: From the kernel's point of view, page tables are "kernel heap"; just some data structures, which happen to be aligned 4K chunks, that need to be allocated and deallocated on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the "Physical memory map" region for?

Direct-mapping of all physical RAM (usually with hugepages) allows easy access to memory given a physical address.  (i.e. add an offset to generate a virtual address you can use to load or store from there.)

Having phys<->virt be cheap makes it easier to manage memory allocations, so you can primarily track what regions of physical memory are in use.

This is how `kmalloc` works: it returns a kernel virtual address that points into the direct-mapped region.  This is great: it doesn't have to spend any time finding free virtual address space as well, just bookkeeping for physical memory.  And it doesn't have to create or modify any page tables (And freeing doesn't have to tear down page tables and `invlpg`.)

`kmalloc` requires the memory to be contiguous in physical memory, not stitching together multiple 4k pages into a contiguous *virtual* allocation (that's what `vmalloc` does), so that's one reason to maybe not use `kmalloc` for everything, like for larger allocations that might fail or have to stop and defrag or page out memory if the kernel can't find enough contiguous physical pages.  Which it couldn't do in a context that must run without pre-emption, like in an interrupt handler.   (Correct me if I'm wrong, I don't regularly actually look at Linux kernel code.  Regardless of actual Linux details, the basics of this way of handling allocation is important and relevant to any OS that direct-maps all physical RAM.)

Related:

- [What is the rationality of Linux kernel's mapping as much RAM as possible in direct-mapping(linear mapping) area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370435/what-is-the-rationality-of-linux-kernels-mapping-as-much-ram-as-possible-in-dir)
- [Confusion about different meanings of "HighMem" in Linux Kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68091247/confusion-about-different-meanings-of-highmem-in-linux-kernel) re: how Linux uses physical RAM that it doesn't have enough virtual address-space to keep mapped all the time.  (On architectures where Linux supports the concept of Highmem, e.g. i386 but [not x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72417308/why-4-level-paging-can-only-cover-64-tib-of-physical-address)).  Still, thinking about that can be a useful thought exercise in how kernels have to deal with memory, and why it's nice that x86-64 kernels generally don't have to deal with that pain.

  [Linux Torvalds has ranted](https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/) about 32-bit x86 PAE which expanded physical address space but *not* virtual, when 4GiB virtual was already not enough to comfortably deal with 4GiB physical.  It's a useful perspective on how this looks from an OS developer's perspective.

> I know the 4-page tables are found in the high canonical region but where exactly are they? (data, code, stack, heap or physical memory map?)

**Page tables for user-space task are in physical memory dynamically allocated by the kernel, probably with `kmalloc`.**  I haven't looked at the code.  Every user-space page-table refers to the page directories for the kernel part of virtual address space, which are also stored somewhere.

They're only accessed by the CPU by physical address, so there's no need for there to be a virtual mapping of them other than the direct mapping of all physical RAM.

(The CPU accesses them on TLB miss, to fetch a PTE with the translation for this virtual address.  But if they used virtual addresses themselves, you'd have a catch-22 unless there was a way for the OS to prime the TLB with an entry for the virtual address in CR3, and so on.  Much better to just have the OS put physical linear addresses into CR3 and the page-directory / page-table entries.)

Comment: `kmalloc` is for allocating small in-kernel data structures, less than one page.  Since the page tables take up entire pages, I believe one would use `alloc_pages` to get a single physical page.  https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/mm-api.html#c.alloc_pages

Answer (score 1):

For Linux on x86-64, each process has its own page tables.  The page tables are independent 4KiB physical pages that can be allocated anywhere in physical memory. The page tables are not part of the virtual address space -- they are accessed by the page table walker hardware using their physical addresses with the bit fields of the requested virtual address as indices into the page table hierarchy. The control register CR3 contains the physical address of the 4KiB page that holds the root of the page table tree for the currently running process. The kernel knows the CR3 of each process (since it must be saved and restored on context switches), so the kernel can walk a process's page tables in software (by emulating what the page table walker does in hardware) for any desired virtual address.